# How to handle error 404 when total items is lower than" per_page" flask pagination?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am developing a web application with Flask Python.

In my application, there is a report page that displays a table of results with Flask pagination.

At the bottom of my table, I added a "select options" field called "number_result_per_page" to let the user choose the "per_page" parameters (number of items per page).

[image]

I made a javascript that reloads the page with the "per_page" parameters updated according to this user's choice.

**PROBLEM :**

My problem is if the user is almost on the last page, and he decides to display "100" results per page, and there are less than 100 results to display, I get a 404 error.

[image]

I am sure I am not the only one who faced this kind of issue. Is there any solution to avoid this scenario?

Or can I catch this particular error 404 to display an "error" popup and reload the previous page which was correct?

Here is sample of my code:

```
# Route
@app.route('/task_user_report/<int:task_user_id>/view', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def task_user_report(task_user_id):
    args = request.args
    per_page_task_report = args.get("per_page_task_report", 1, type=int)
    actions = db_mysql.session.query(Action).filter_by(id_task_user=task_user_id)  \
                        .filter(Action.id_contact==Contact.id)  \
                        .paginate(page=page_task_report, per_page=per_page_task_report)
    
    render_template(render_html,title='Task Report',legend='Task Report',actions=actions,  \
                        per_page_task_report=per_page_task_report)


# Template

<div class="row justify-content-center" style="width: 95%;">
    <div class="col-7 my-auto text-right">
        <div class="text-center mt-4" style="display: inline-block;">
            <nav aria-label="Pagination">
                <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
                    {% for page_num in actions.iter_pages(left_edge=1,right_edge=1,left_current=1, right_current=2) %}
                        {% if page_num %}
                            {% if actions.page == page_num %}
                                <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link"  href="{{ url_for('task_user_report',task_user_id=task_user_id,page_task_report=page_num,per_page_task_report=per_page_task_report) }}">{{ page_num }}</a>
                            {% else %}
                                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link"  href="{{ url_for('task_user_report',task_user_id=task_user_id,page_task_report=page_num,per_page_task_report=per_page_task_report) }}">{{ page_num }}</a>
                            {% endif %}

                        {% else %}
                            <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;...&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>

                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-5 my-auto text-right">
    <select style="width:180px!important;display: inline-block;" id="number_result_per_page" class="form-control form-control-sm w-25 text-right" onchange="change_per_page()">
    
        <option value="10" 
        {% if per_page_task_report== 10 %}
        selected
        {% endif %}  
        >10 results per page</option>
    <option value="25"
    {% if per_page_task_report== 25 %}
        selected
    {% endif %}  
    >25 results per page</option>
    <option value="50"
    {% if per_page_task_report== 50 %}
        selected
    {% endif %}  
    
    >50 results per page</option>
    <option value="100"
    {% if per_page_task_report== 100 %}
        selected
    {% endif %}  
    
    >100 results per page</option>
    </select></div>
</div>       

# Javascript
<script>
  function change_per_page() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    // we get value of per page option
    var per_page_option = document.getElementById("number_result_per_page");
    var per_page_option_value = per_page_option.value;

    // We check if parameter exist in url
    var is_per_page = url.includes("per_page_task_report"); 
    if (is_per_page == true){
      var queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
          
      // new value of "page_task_report" is set to "per_page_option_value"
      queryParams.set('per_page_task_report', String(per_page_option_value));
      // change the search property of the main url
      history.pushState(null, null, "?"+queryParams.toString());
      var new_url = window.location.href;
    }
    else{
      // There are 2 cases : 
      // [1] url doesn't have any parameters (ex:http://127.0.0.1:5000/task_user_report/2/view)

      // [2] url has a parameter (ex:http://127.0.0.1:5000/task_user_report/2/view?page_task_report=2)
      var is_page_task_report = url.includes("page_task_report"); 
      if (is_page_task_report == true){
        var new_url = url + '&per_page_task_report=' +  per_page_option_value;
        
      }
      else{
        var new_url = url + '?per_page_task_report=' +  per_page_option_value;
      }
      
    }
    window.location.replace(new_url);
    
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `paginate()` call, set `error_out=False` like this, `paginate(..., error_out=False)`

The default is `True`. This behavior is not always desired though. If you are using Flask as an API backend, this can sometimes cause errors. It's up to you how you want to handle it by either providing an empty result set or by defaulting the page back to one when no results are returned.